# dimens.xml directory is not found in android studio 2.1.1

Tags: android

I have taken a new project in Android Studio 2.1.1.But there is no dimens.xml file found, here is the screen shot of this: [image: This is my project image, where in the code the dimens related codes are red, but there is no dimens directory.]

Comment: You can manually create the `dimens.xml` folder

Comment: @Vucko how to create dimens.xml folder?

Comment: Simply create the folder in the `values` folder and add the xml's containing the dimension in it. Or if it's a new project, and you hadn't done any programming, create it again, you should get this folder created automatically...

Comment: @Vucko thanx i'll try.